# how to make an entered text box value upto two decimal points

Tags: php, regex

```
<div class="form-group">
 <?php
  $data = array('name' => 'Basicvalue','value' => set_value('Basicvalue'),'id'=>'Basicvalue',  'class' => 'form-control' ,'readonly' => 'true');
  echo form_input(($data));
  ?>
</div>
```

This is my text box and when I entered an input, it should display with two decimals. How can I do that?

eg: If I entered 11, then the field should display it as 11.00

Comment: Please Refer, [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you need your action in client side Use following Jquery function :

```
<div class="form-group">
     <?php
      $data = array('name' => 'Basicvalue','value' => set_value('Basicvalue'),'id'=>'Basicvalue',  'class' => 'form-control changetodecimal' ,'readonly' => 'true');
    echo form_input(($data));
      ?>
  </div>  

<script>
$(document).on('change',".changetodecimal", function(){ 
    var inputvalues = $(this).val();
    var resultvalues=parseFloat(inputvalues).toFixed(2); 
    $(this).val(resultvalues);

});
</script>
```

If you want Server Side (PHP) use following function :

```
echo number_format($number, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [number_format():](http://php.net/number_format)

```
return number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');
```

Example:

```
$foo = "105";
echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  number_format($yournymber,2);

```
<?php
    $num=3;

    $decimalNum=number_format($num,2);

    echo $decimalNum;
?>
```

You will get the output 3.00

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you need to use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function:

```
number_format($num,2);
echo number_format(11,2); // 11.00
```

Numbers are formatted with decimals. In the above example, second parameter defines how many values you want post the decimal.